# Identify Special Characters and numbers in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In my case, I have a `varchar` variable like `Test1@abc`. I want to identify the special characters and numbers in that string and return them. This string can only include alphabetic letters, space, and underscore (a-z, A-Z, space,_). All other characters are not allowed. I want to return them. Thank you.

```
DECLARE @StringVal VARCHAR(250) = 'Test1@abc' 
IF(--condition)
BEGIN
    --output -> 1,@
END
```

Comment: If the string *"can only include alphabetic letters, space, and underscore(a-z, A-Z, space,_)"* then why are there only characters in there? Clearly that ***are*** allowed.

Comment: Also, SQL Server 2008 reached end of Life well over a year ago, you really should be looking at upgrade paths ASAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the results just printed out, you can use:

```
DECLARE @StringVal VARCHAR(400) = 'Test1@abc';  
DECLARE @expres VARCHAR(MAX) = '%[^a-zA-Z_]%';

WHILE @StringVal LIKE @expres
BEGIN
    PRINT SUBSTRING(@stringVal, PATINDEX(@expres, @stringVal), 1);
    SET @stringval = STUFF(@stringVal, 1, PATINDEX(@expres, @stringVal), '');
END;
```

If you want them output as a string, you can concatenate them:

```
DECLARE @StringVal VARCHAR(400) = 'Test1@abc';
DECLARE @expres VARCHAR(MAX) = '%[^a-zA-Z_]%';
DECLARE @output VARCHAR(MAX) = '';

WHILE @StringVal LIKE @expres
BEGIN
    SET @output = @output + SUBSTRING(@stringVal, PATINDEX(@expres, @stringVal), 1);
    SET @stringval = STUFF(@stringVal, 1, PATINDEX(@expres, @stringVal), '');
END;

SELECT @output;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=371f33543ea4c9acd101fd928ad05e94) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Regex**

```
DECLARE @StringVal VARCHAR(400) = 'Test1@abc'

DECLARE @expres VARCHAR(50) = '%[^~,@,#,$,%,&,*,(,),.,!,0-9]%'

WHILE PATINDEX( @expres, @StringVal ) > 0
SET @StringVal = Replace(REPLACE( @StringVal, SUBSTRING( @StringVal, PATINDEX( @expres, @StringVal ), 1 ),''),'-',' ')

IF(@StringVal LIKE '%[~,@,#,$,%,&,*,(,),.,!,0-9]%')
BEGIN
SELECT @StringVal AS [Special Char]
END
ELSE
SELECT 'No Special Characters'  AS [Non Special Char]
```

Comment: @prasanga . . . I don't think the best solution involves listing the characters the *cannot* be included.  It is simple enough to express the logic based on those that *can* be included.

Comment: If u think So, then u can change the logic instead of not including the Special Characters , DECLARE @expres VARCHAR(50) = '%[a-zA-Z]%' - we can include the alphabets in both the declaration & Conditional Check (IF) stmts